# Apache Ivy resolve dependencies using Eclipse workspace during Ant build

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, ivy, workspace

I'm using Apache Ivy with Eclipse (IvyDE) and trying to solve the following issue. **I have two projects, IvyParent and IvyChild, where the child depends on the parent.** I have the option selected for Eclipse Ivy Classpath Container to "Resolve dependencies in workspace".

The Eclipse autobuilder is working great - I get all my Ivy dependencies downloaded and included. **I have both the parent and child projects open and I can make realtime edits to the parent and see the compilation changes in the child.**

The problem is when I try to use Ant to build the child project into a jar. My question is, **how can I leverage the Workspace resolver during an explicit Ant build?**

I've looked into Ivy filesystem resolvers, but what I'm trying to avoid is having to Ant rebuild the parent project explicitly before Ant building the child.

The error I get is the following:

```
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      module not found: org.example#ParentModule;latest.integration
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== local: tried
[ivy:retrieve]  ...
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== shared: tried
[ivy:retrieve]  ...
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]  ...
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: org.example#ParentModule;latest.integration: not found
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\user\workspace\IvyExampleChild\build.xml:15: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details
```

Here is the parent project ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <info organisation="org.example" module="ParentModule" status="integration" />
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Here is the child project ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <info organisation="org.example" module="ChildModule" status="integration" />
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.example" name="ParentModule" rev="latest.integration"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Here is the child build.xml:

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="ChildModule" default="release">    
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="build.dir.classes" value="${build.dir}/classes" />

    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="output.jar" value="${build.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" />

    <target name="clean">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />
        </delete>
    </target>

    <target name="apache-ivy" depends="clean">
        <ivy:retrieve />
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.build.path" conf="default" />
    </target>

    <target name="release" depends="apache-ivy">
        <echo message="compiling ${src.dir}..." />

        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir.classes}" />

        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir.classes}" classpathref="ivy.build.path"/>
        <jar destfile="${output.jar}" basedir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a resolver and publishing problem.  Your build for your ParentModule needs to 'publish' its jar to a specific directory.  Then your child module build should be using a resolver that can find this specific directory.

So.. for example, ivy_settings might look like:

```
<ivysettings>
  <properties file="./ivysettings.properties"/>
  <property name="repository.dir" value="${ivy.build.dir}/repository"/>
  <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain">
      <filesystem name="internal">
        <ivy pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/ivy.xml" />
        <artifact pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/[artifact].[ext]" />
      </filesystem>
      <ibiblio name="maven2" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

and your build.xml files should have

```
  <ivy:settings file="${ivy.build.dir}/ivysettings.xml" />
```

What's happening here is we're telling ivy about a directory (...../repository) for the locally build jar files.

So your parent build now has in it's build.xml a 'publish' target:

```
<target name="publish" depends="jar, jarSources" description="--> publish this project in the ivy repository">
  <delete file="${dist.dir}/lib/ivy.xml"/>
  <ivy:publish artifactspattern="${dist.dir}/lib/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"
          resolver="internal"
          status="integration"
          overwrite="true"/>
  <echo message="project ${ant.project.name} integration published" />
</target>
```

So.. run that and confirm your ParentModule.jar file shows up in your repository directory.

Once there, your child module should be able to 'resolve' your parent module jar file.